# Should questions purely about IDEs be tagged with the language the IDE deals with?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across [this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983625/...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983625/xcode-3-1-2-locks-up-when-loading-c-project) question and although the IDE in question deals with c++, the question itself doesn't relate to c++ at all.

This brings up 2 questions:

1. Should questions purely about IDEs be tagged with the language the IDE deals with?
2. And if so, if the IDE deals with multiple language (e.g. Visual Studio) and if the feature in question isn't available for all languages should it then be tagged with the appropriate language, a tag containing both the IDE and the language (e.g. VisualStudio-c++) or omit the language altogether?

Answer (score 6):

My Opinion:

1. No
2. A combined tag of both the IDE and language (in that order)

Comment: I concur, the language tag implies the question is about the language itself.  For example, a person might be an expert in Java, but may know nothing about, say, JBuilder.  Tagging a JBuilder question with Java would be wrong.